# Nuxt @onloadstart not triggering function using beforeCreate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

New to Nuxt and SSR. What I'm trying to do is straightforward: I'm trying to trigger a function before the page loads that will SSR my firestore data. If I add a button with @onclick, it works fine. But when I try to replace the Button/OnClick with @onloadstart or something similar, nothing happens.

What am I missing? I suspect I’m thinking about this through a client side lens. Not a SSR lens.

```
 <template @onloadstart="beforeCreate()">
  <section>
    <div>
      <div v-for="article in articles" id="articleCardList" :key="article">
        <v-card elevation="1" outlined>
          <div class="d-flex">
            <v-avatar class="ma-1" size="125" tile>
              <v-img :src="article.thumbnail"></v-img>
            </v-avatar>
            <div>
              <v-card-title
                class="text-h5 text-wrap d-flex justify-space-between text-caption"
                v-text="article.title"
              >
                {{ article.title }}
              </v-card-title>
            </div>
          </div>
        </v-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
<script>
import { fireDb } from '~/plugins/firebase.js'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      articles: [],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    async asyncData() {
      this.articles = []

      await fireDb
        .collection('articles')
        .get()
        .then((querySnapShot) => {
          querySnapShot.forEach((doc) => {
            this.articles.push({
              id: doc.id,
              title: doc.data().title,
              description: doc.data().description,
              thumbnail: doc.data().thumbnail,
              date: doc.data().date,
              link: doc.data().link,
              source: doc.data().source,
            })
            console.log(this.articles)
          })
        })
    },
    beforeCreate() {
      window.addEventListener('beforeCreate', this.asyncData)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's `@click` actually. Did you tried it? `@click`is client side only tho.

Comment: Otherwise, using `fetch()` hook and managing a loading state could be nice while fetching the data from firebase. You could also use `created()`but this one will not block the rendering until it's done fetching. Actually, only `asyncData` does but it's just between a page transition hence, if you arrive on this page it will not be handled. Not sure but maybe a middleware could be blocking, need to try it out. Does your event listener work btw?

Comment: Yes, if I add a button with @click=“asyncData”, it works. But I don’t want to trigger data loading with a manual click. I want the data to load automatically on render.

Comment: No, the `beforeCreate`. Does it trigger something at all? Otherwise, I gave you the alternative (`fetch()`hook).

Comment: There is a helper for this btw: `$fetchState.pending` as stated in the docs: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-fetch/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close to a working solution in terms of having the component automatically fetch data before the page loads. Instead of `beforeCreate`, you'd use [the `asyncData` hook](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching/#async-data) (which seems to be your initial attempt).

The problem is you've declared `asyncData` as a *component method*, but it needs to be at the top level of the object definition for it to be used as a component hook.

```js
export default {
  // ✅ declared as a hook
  asyncData() {...},

  methods: {
    // ❌ this should be at the top level
    asyncData() {...} 
  },
}
```

Be aware that `asyncData` can only be used in page or layout components.   Otherwise, you need to switch to [the `fetch` hook](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching/#the-fetch-hook).

`asyncData()` has no access to `this` (as it's run before the page component), so those references should be removed. Instead, `asyncData()` should return an object of data similar to that returned from `data()` (i.e., `{ ​articles }`):

```js
export default {
  ​asyncData() {
    ​const articles = []

    ​await fireDb
      ​.collection('articles')
      ​.get()
      ​.then((querySnapShot) => {
        ​querySnapShot.forEach((doc) => {
          ​articles.push(/*...*/)
        ​})
      ​})

    console.log(articles)
    return { articles }
  }
}
```

Comment: I noticed `return articles` inside `forEach`, which does not make sense. That return needs to be the last line of `asyncData()`, outside the `forEach`.